# Validate required radiobutton on .validate() rules jquery function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I have radio button on my form and I wan't to required validate it but I don't know how validate it on rules. It will show error field if not checked Thank you

```js
$("[name='formName']").validate({
        rules: {
            radName: {}
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

 <form name="formName" method="post" action="#">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radNamae" value="1">
      <label for="rdb-illustration">Label 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radNamae" value="2">
      <label for="rdb-illustration">Label 2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radNamae" value="3">
      <label for="rdb-illustration">Label 3</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn-gen" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("[name='formName']").validate({
  rules: {
    radName: {
      required: true
    }
  },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var name    = $(element).attr("name");
    var obj    = $("#" + name + "_validate");
        error.appendTo(obj);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form name="formName" method="post" action="#">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radName" value="1">
    <label for="rdb-illustration">Label 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radName" value="2">
    <label for="rdb-illustration">Label 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radName" value="3">
    <label for="rdb-illustration">Label 3</label>
  </div>
   <div id='radName_validate'></div>
  <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn-gen" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: how to put the error field on after the last rad button or after the div?

Comment: You can set it using `errorPlacement`. Answer updated

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. But how can I make the errorPlacement exclusive to to radName only. Sorry only new to jquery validation. all my error placement were good but if you try to add another input and validate. all the other error fields goes to the specific div

Comment: I updated my answer. This will allow you to create specific divs for specific form errors.